# Implications of `DPB size > level limit`?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, encoding, h.264, lossless-compression

I'm using ffmpeg and the libx264rgb codec to encode 5760x3240 PNG sequences into lossless .mp4 files. When I do this, I get the warning in yellow text:

`DPB size (16 frames, 1169280 mbs) > level limit (9 frames, 696320 mbs)`

I'm not completely sure what it means. Although it is slow, the encoder does finish encoding the files into a .mp4 file, from which I can extract the frames again losslessly.

What does this warning mean, and what is the implication?

Comment: Remove `-level` option in your command. You also probably have a slow preset set. Not really needed.

Comment: @Gyan, I'm not using -level, but I am using the veryslow preset. Why shouldn't I use it?

Comment: In that case, ignore the warning. As long as the output will be played on a PC only, you should be fine.